# How can I get my .NET XML Documentation Comments into Conflunce

Tags: .net, documentation, comments, documentation-generation, confluence

I'd like to import my .Net XML Documentation Comments (the documentation based on the code tags, automatically generated by the compiler with the /doc switch) into Atlassian Confluence.

I've used Doxygen to generate some HTML which looks great, but I'd love to have something I can dump straight into Confluence.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe Confluence can take markdown - Sandcastle claims to be able to put out markdown, but I haven't had much luck yet in getting it to do so. Good question!

Comment: Very good question. NDoc was a great tool but had it's days, Doxygen is nice but feeding this documentation straight into Confluence would be better even. Probably a good idea for someone creating a Confluence plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straighforward and easy to maintain option would be to call the Confluence API to upload content; it is well documented so it should be the same as calling any REST API from .Net, once you have the content as you indicate.

https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/REST/latest/#content-createContent

EDIT: while there are many questions in SO addressing how to call an API from .Net, just to have the full reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client